# Criteria select returning a Collection instead of a List. How to fix that error?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, criteria-api

Basically, I am using criteria to get a name and a list from a repository.

My constructor:

```
public Servidor(String nome, List<VinculoFuncional> vinculosFuncionais) {
    super(nome);
    this.vinculosFuncionais = vinculosFuncionais;
}
```

My implementation:

```
@Override
public List<Servidor> buscarServidorPorCpf(Long cpf) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Servidor> query = cb.createQuery(Servidor.class);
    Root<Servidor> servidorRoot = query.from(Servidor.class);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    if(cpf != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(servidorRoot.get("cpf"), cpf));
    }

    query.multiselect(servidorRoot.get("nome"), servidorRoot.get("vinculosFuncionais"));

    query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

My controller:

```
@GetMapping
public List<Servidor> buscarServidor(@RequestParam Long cpf) {
    return repository.buscarServidorPorCpf(cpf);
}
```

Error I get:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [br.gov.dataprev.siprev.modelo.servidor.Servidor]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.util.Collection [select new br.gov.dataprev.siprev.modelo.servidor.Servidor(generatedAlias0.nome, generatedAlias0.vinculosFuncionais) from br.gov.dataprev.siprev.modelo.servidor.Servidor as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.cpf=84579030478L]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [br.gov.dataprev.siprev.modelo.servidor.Servidor]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.util.Collection [select new br.gov.dataprev.siprev.modelo.servidor.Servidor(generatedAlias0.nome, generatedAlias0.vinculosFuncionais) from br.gov.dataprev.siprev.modelo.servidor.Servidor as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.cpf=84579030478L]",
>     "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [br.gov.dataprev.siprev.modelo.servidor.Servidor]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.util.Collection [select new br.gov.dataprev.siprev.modelo.servidor.Servidor(generatedAlias0.nome, generatedAlias0.vinculosFuncionais) from br.gov.dataprev.siprev.modelo.servidor.Servidor as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.cpf=84579030478L]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong. `Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [br.gov.dataprev.siprev.modelo.servidor.Servidor]` you are using a DTO and it should have a specific constructor, apparently it doesn't have that. That is what the error is telling you. It isn't complaining about the return type of the method.

Comment: @M.Deinum actually I 'm not using DTO for that. I'm using the constructor from my model Servidor.

Comment: Well y9ou aren't as the constructor it is looking for doesn't exists. So you have an entity with probably only a default constructor NOT a constructor taking a string and collection of elements. This is due to the `multiselect` it will return only those columns and will thus look for a constructor to create an object.So change the list to a collection in your constructor. Or remove the multiselect and retrieve the full entity.

Comment: @M.Deinum so I created a DTO, My DTO constructor got same `String nome, List<VinculoFuncional> vinculosFuncionais`. I realized my return method `getResultList() ` can only passing **nome** without error , but not the list. I mean if I remove list, I get **nome** on postman, but if both I got an error. I still think it's returning a collection while the constructor is supposed to get a list instead. If I try to change the type list to collection I get a different error, some SQL syntax error expecting some charactere. I still can't figure out this problem.

Comment: The problem is your constructor NOT the `getResultList` method. The constructor must accept a colleciton NOT a `List`.